# Customer in more than customer group

Tags: customer, discount, customer-group, manufacturer

One customer asked me, if it's possible to **add a customer** in **more than one customer group**. He wants to give his customers a **discount** which is **manufacturer based**.

Example: 
Customer 1 get a discount of 5% for manufacturer A and a discount of 10% for manufacturer B. 
Customer 2 gets a discount of 10% for manufacturer A and a discount of 15% for manufacturer B.

The idea was to solve this with several customer groups. Or are there better solutions?

Comment: You want to create many customer group,based on customer group you want to manage discount or single customer you want to handle different customer group

Answer (score 0):

To solve this your thought sounds correct.
A customer is typically only ever to be in one customer group.
So if you have a specific group for manufacturer "a" to give 5 % and manufacturer "b" to give 10% off and another group to do the reverse I would think that would be the simplest solution to this.

But that's not saying that is the only solution.
Another solution you could do to have a promo based on another attribute you set.

By creating a new attribute and assigning certain values to that and have that determine the customers that are allowed to have the percentage off would save you time changing group prices for each of your products.

It all depends on what concerns you have with your current solution and how much time you plan on investing to make one solution work.

If you have any questions on my suggestion please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your idea with a new attribute. It sounds good and makes sense but there is another condition. My customer has the discount only for several product groups for each manufacturer. So we can't say there is a overall discount for each manufacturer. 

A promo based discount is out of question then. Discounts I could set in the advanced pricing section with a mass import. The question is, if there is an extension or something that allows me, to add a customer in several customer groups.